# UserDataSvc_6038b: unable to disable this suspicious service

Tags: privacy, windows-10, spyware

On Windows 10, I just discovered a running service named UserDataSvc_6038b. It's description is as follows:

> Provides apps access to structured user data, including contact info, calendars, messages, and other content. If you stop or disable this service, apps that use this data might not work correctly.

Path to executable:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k UnistackSvcGroup

Startup type

> Manual

I am unable to set this service to the Disabled startup state.

Edit: Using regedit, I was able to locate the service at:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UserDataSvc_6038b

and was able to set the Start value to: 4 (disabled)

While in the registry, I noticed the description for this service is:

> @%SystemRoot%\system32\UserDataAccessRes.dll,-14000

Googling this service returned "*Your search - "userdatasvc_6038b" - did not match any documents.*"

This seems to be a unique, unwanted service to me. Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you're genuinely concerned that this service is/was malicious, there's a few things you can do:

1. Check the properties on the DLL listed.  Is it signed?  By whom?
2. Upload the DLL to VirusTotal.  If you have the same version as another source, you'll get [this results page](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/2627f62f2aec930974854bb680cb0b2048012279ed2fbf93da24fa6a3fe46b3f/detection) that shows 0/57 detection ratio, and an author of Microsoft corporation.

I don't have a Windows 10 box handy to check myself for the DLL in question.

If you search just for 'UserDataSvc', you'll find lots of other people asking about a service with that name + 5 hex characters.  Likely Microsoft has done something to make a unique service.  (Maybe it runs one per user on multi-user machines and 6038b is related to your account?  I doubt it's part of your SID...)

Just from reading about it, I'm fairly confident this is a benign (well, intended by Microsoft) service.